# I have lose my previous commit github by gitbash

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash, git-commit

I am was updating my project to github by using git bash, but this was not updating, and i have try to google my problem, and then by using some command my project updated to git hub repositery,
but my previous commit is not there.

> I didn't delete my project, but when my project was not updating, then
> i had deleted " git " directory which was the hidden directory.

My command what i have used.

```
       182  git init
  183  git add .
  184  git commit -m "initial relese 3*3"
  185  git branch -M main
  186  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  187  git push -u origin main
  188  git push -u origin main -force
  189  git push -u origin main --force
  190  exit
  191  git init
  192  git add -A
  193  git commit -m "working 10*10 or dynamic play board and shift hard to soft code"
  194  git remote rm origin
  195  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  196  git push -u origin main
  197  git init
  198  git add -A
  199  git commit -m "10*10 board solved some issue"
  200  git remote rm origin
  201  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  202  git push -u origin main
  203  exit
  204  git init
  205  git add .
  206  git commit -m "initial realese"
  207  git branch -M main
  208  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/ShakshiTradres.git
  209  git push -u origin main
  210  git init
  211  git add -A
  212  git commit "10*10 board now playboard and players datasource is different"
  213  git commit -m "10*10 board now playboard and players datasource is different"
  214  git remote rm origin
  215  git remote add origin https:///github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  216  git push -u origin main
  217  git init
  218  git add -A
  219  git commit -m "10*10 board checkDiagonalsForWin"
  220  git remote rm origin
  221  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  222  git push -u origin main
  223  git init
  224  git add -A
  225  git commit -m "10*10 board now players will save in h2 and palyboard will save into mysql"
  226  git remote rm origin
  227  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe
  228  git push -u origin main
  229  exit
  230  git init
  231  git add -A
  232  git commit -m "remove lots of bugs and use recomended pettern"
  233  git remote rm origin
  234  git remote add origin
  235  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  236  git push -u main
  237  git push -u main --force
  238  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  239  git push -u origin main
  240  git push -u origin main --force
  241  exit
  242  git init
  243  git add -A
  244  git commit -m "impletemns integration testing and solved some issue"
  245  git remote rm origin
  246  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  247  git push -u origin main
  248  git push -u origin main
  249  git init
  250  git add -A
  251  git commit -m "complete game score"
  252  git remote rm origin
  253  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  254  git push -u origin main
  255  git clone https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  256  v
  257  git init
  258  git add -A
  259  git commit "solved some issue"
  260  git commit -m "solved some issue"
  261  git remote rm origin
  262  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  263  git push -u origin main
  264  exit
  265  git init
  266  git add -A
  267  git commit -m "integration testing"
  268  git remote rm origin
  269  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  270  git push -u main
  271  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  272  git push -u main
  273  git remote add https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  274  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  275  git push -u main
  276  git push -u main --force
  277  git init
  278  git add -A
  279  git commit -m "integration testing"
  280  git remote rm origin
  281  git remote add https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  282  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  283  git push -u origin main
  284  git push -u origin main
  285  git init
  286  git add -A
  287  git commit -m "integration testing & solve some issue"
  288  git remote rm origin
  289  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  290  git push -u origin main
  291  git init
  292  git add -A
  293  git commit -m "integration testing"
  294  git remote rm origin
  295  git remote rm origin
  296  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe
  297  git push -u origin main
  298  git remote add origin https://github.com/sainivinit/TicTacToe.git
  299  git push -u origin main
  300  git push -u origin main --force
  301  git push -u origin master
  302  git show-ref
  303  git push origin HEAD:main
  304  git show-ref
  305  git push -u origin main
  306  git push origin HEAD:main
  307  git init
  308  git add .
  309  git commit -m "integration testing"
  310  git push -u origin master
  311  git push -u origin master --force
  312  git push -u origin master --force
  313  git init
  314  git add -A
  315  git commit -m "test integration"
  316  git push origin HEAD:main
  317  git push origin HEAD:main --force
  318  git commit -m "test integration"
  319  git reflog
  320  git reflog
  321  history
```

[image: image here]

**I have lose my 11 previous commits.**

Comment: The history you pasted show 6 callls to `git init`. Can you describe in more details the actions you took around these `git init` actions (outside of `git-bash` probably) ? For example : did you repeatedly delete your complete project directory, create a new empty directory, and run `git init` within that empty directory ?

Comment: No i didn't delete my project, but when  my project was not updating, then i had deleted " git " directory which was the hidden directory.

Comment: Ok, this point is important to understanding your issue, please edit your question to add it in your description.

Comment: You also talk anout 11 commits, but we don't see 11 `git commit` commands in your list. Did you use another tool to run git actions ? perhaps from your IDE ? or from a GUI tool such as git-extension ?

Comment: Now i have added that.

Comment: I am very confused about why tou calles `git init` so much time.

Comment: What do you mean by "but when my project was not updating"?

Answer (score 0):

Why your history was deleted :

The `.git/` directory contains all of git database for your local clone. If you delete that directory, you delete all trace of exiting branches, commits, and reflog.

If you then run `git init` followed by `git commit`, you create a new history, with one single commit in it (and no trace of the previously existing commits).
Running `git push --force` with such a history will instruct git to replace the *remote* branch with that single commit.

So : you deleted your local reflog (when deleting `.git/`) and you dropped your remote history (when running `git push -f`).

---

What you can do to recover that :

you would have to look into github's reflog. You don't have a direct access to that through git, but there is some way to access it through github's api.

Try for example the commands suggested in this post :

https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f

Comment: Good. And obviously : don't delete your local `.git/` directory ...

Comment: As @GenoChen commented : if you have issues with "updating your project", please ask a separate question, with more details on that point